# "Some required Android Components are missing. Double-click here and follow the prompts to install them.", But nothing happens when i click on it

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

to begin with, i am running `Windows 10 (Version 1909)` and `Visual Studio Professional 2017 (Version 15.9.23)`. I'm trying to start a new Xamarin.Forms project for an Android App but the very template doesn't seem to build. i've already updated the NuGet Packages and still no luck.

the Error List shows these:
[image]

When i do click on it, a EULA Window appears and asks me to Agree to it. But when i do, nothing else happens. But i do notice this log on the `Output > Xamarin` Window:

[image]

However, checking on the path. The files are there and the `SDK Manager.exe` works fine - it opens a window and shows all the SDKs available, downloaded, obsolete, etc.

Now, when i try to open up `Tools > Android > Android SDK Manager...`, it shows an empty window with an error message on the bottom right:

[image]

I'm really clueless here. i tried searching online but nothing good shows up. i tried [this one](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/348850/view.html) but it didn't help or fix t he problem.

Comment: Can you connect to the network? If you use Proxy to connect network, please disable it, Change another network to make a test.

Comment: i can. and i have no issues with my internet connection at the moment. which makes it more weird.

Comment: Please open the Visual studio installer, click the Repair selection like following sceenshot.https://imgur.com/a/sBmV6MN . After that, please re-start your computer, if this issue is still existed.